# Why hydrogen gas tube produce hydrogen atomic spectrum

Tags: experimental-chemistry, spectroscopy, atoms

To measure the atomic hydrogen spectrum people often uses hydrogen gas tubes as light source.
Since the gas in the tube is the molecule $H_2$ , why we obtain the spectrum of atomic hydrogen?
My guess is that because the voltage is so high, so that the molecules are totally dissociated.
If you could give me some reference I would be grateful.

Comment: Think  thoroughly about  possible answers to your questions and search for them before asking.   
Provide in the question elaboration what you already know, what you have thought about, 
what you tried to search for in textbooks and online resources, 
what you found, understood or not, where you failed. 
Elaborated questions attract elaborated answers and vice versa. 
Include in  the question all eventually relevant circumstances to prevent wrong assumptions and requests for clarifications. 
Questions without  *explicit* own effort  are not very welcome, and may be closed.

Comment: Consider the effect of accelerated ions and relative intensity of atomic and molecular spectrum.

Comment: Of course, $\ce{H2}$ is dissociated into $2$ $\ce{ H}$ atoms, but this dissociation is not total. It is not necessary. Please think before asking !

Comment: why is not necessary?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira, if you have 10^9 *molecules* and 1 ion, does that prevent the ion from emitting (or absorbing) radiation??

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I guess you mean atoms not ions (with respect to hydrogen discharge tube).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik if there is more molecules of hydrogen there is more probability to get the hydrogen molecule spectrum

Comment: The answer is what I posted here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768678/313612. The high voltage results in high energy electrons colliding with the hydrogen molecules, resulting in some of the molecules dissociating into hydrogen atoms. So the discharge has hydrogen atoms, both excited and ground state, plus hydrogen molecules, both excited and ground state, plus various ions and, of course, electrons. Anything excited **might** emit its characteristic light as it de-excites. De-excitation might just result in heat. Please upvote my answer if it helps you! Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: One more thing: in my linked answer, the Fulcher alpha bands are from the hydrogen molecules. So you definitely get both atomic emission, from the excited hydrogen atoms, and molecular emission, from the excited hydrogen molecules.